# Oracle DB dynamic returned value based on ID

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have one table that have three fields

```
Material QTY MONTH_YEAR
1 , 1 2020-07
1 , 2 2020-04
1 , 2 2020-03
1 , 2 2020-05
2 , 3 2020-10
2 , 4 ,2020-08
2 , 4 ,2020-08
3 , 4 ,2021-08
3 , 4 ,2021-08
3 , 4 ,2020-08
3 , 4 ,2020-08
3 , 4 ,2019-08
```

What i am try to achieve is to return first two records for different material number.

Output

```
Material QTY MONTH_YEAR
1 , 1 2020-07
1 , 2 2020-04
2 , 3 2020-10
2 , 4 ,2020-08
3 , 4 ,2021-08
3 , 4 ,2021-0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first two rows per material? But 2020-07 and 2020-04 are not the first rows for material 1. 2020-03 and 2020-04 are the earliest. Or what is your definition of "first"?

Comment: the first refers to the first two rows that return.

Comment: Is the tie for the row `3 , 4 ,2020-08` intendedly added ?

Comment: Ah, just two rows per material, and you don't care which? Just the first two the DBMS happens to pick?

Comment: "the first two rows that return" In SQL, there is no first row, third row, fifth row or anything else, there is no order at all unless you use an ORDER BY clause. So your question at it currently stands doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test order by material, month_year;

  MATERIAL        QTY MONTH_Y
---------- ---------- -------
         1          2 2020-03
         1          2 2020-04
         1          2 2020-05
         1          1 2020-07
         2          4 2020-08
         2          4 2020-08
         2          3 2020-10
         3          4 2019-08
         3          4 2020-08
         3          4 2020-08
         3          4 2021-08
         3          4 2021-08

12 rows selected.
```

Generally speaking, one option is to *sort* rows by *something* - in my example, it is per each `material` by `month_year` column in ascending order so that the 1st and the 2nd row have these `rn` values: `1` and `2` - and then fetch rows that rank as two highest.

Your desired output shows that you actually want two rows as you literally wrote them, but - that's **suspicious** because for `material = 1` are either 2020-07 and 2020-05 (if sorted in descending order), or 2020-03 and 2020-04 (if sorted in ascending order). If there's no other column that lets us figure out such an output (the one you specified), you're out of luck.

On the other hand, if your desired output is wrong, then fix `order by` clause (in line #3) to let query return values you need (either 2 first, or 2 last rows).

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select material, qty, month_year,
  3       row_number() over (partition by material order by month_year) rn
  4     from test
  5    )
  6  select material, qty, month_year
  7  from temp
  8  where rn <= 2
  9  order by material, month_year;

  MATERIAL        QTY MONTH_Y
---------- ---------- -------
         1          2 2020-03
         1          2 2020-04
         2          4 2020-08
         2          4 2020-08
         3          4 2019-08
         3          4 2020-08

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic function such as `ROW_NUMBER()`(*by which you'll strictly pick two per each match, even a tie occurs*) as follows

```
SELECT Material, qty, month_year
  FROM(
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Material ORDER BY month_year DESC) AS rn,
              t.*
         FROM t
      ) 
 WHERE rn <= 2
```

after sorting descendingly by `month_year` column's values based on the desired output.